# Transit visa for Australia applied for but not granted yet

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, australia

I am an Indian passport holder and have applied for Australian transit visa 10 days ago. It has not been granted yet. Processing time for Australian visas is 6-8 days.

I have to travel to Port Vila, Vanuatu, via Singapore and Brisbane, Australia. I have a 3.5-hour layover in Australia. I'm leaving the day after tomorrow. So, basically, I have one day left to get my visa.

What should be my course of action if I do not get my visa tomorrow? Can I show the proof of application for a transit visa from the Australian home affairs website? Will the authorities at the airport have a database of applications and their status?

The immigration website says that you may not need a transit visa if you are transiting through Australia for not more than 8 hours and not leaving the transit area. Does it apply for everyone?

I have to collect my baggage from one airline and check-in to another airline in Brisbane. Do I have to leave the transit area for that, if the 8-hour thing applies for me?

Comment: In this case you do need a visa. You won’t remain airside.

Answer (score 5):

As per the [Department's website](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/lega/lega/form/immi-faqs/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-through-australia), Indian citizens are **not** eligible for transit without visa arrangements, regardless of whether they remain or exit the airside transit area.  This means you **must** have a visa to travel to Australia.

When checking into your flight to Australia at the first point of departure, the airline will check your Australian visa electronically using the Australian Government's [Advance Passenger Processing](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/busi/Air/APP) (APP) system.  If you do not have a valid Australian transit visa at that time, APP will indicate as such, and you will be denied boarding.

Showing your visa application paperwork will not make a difference, as an application for a visa is not a visa.

You should consider changing your travel plans if you cannot obtain a visa in time.

Comment: well ,transit visa didn't come through. I had to reschedule my tickets.Now once if the transit visa is granted for the original date of departure, do I have to apply for transit visa again for the new date of departur

Comment: @traveller Sorry to hear that.  If you have a new question, please ask it as a new question.